# Writing to multiple columns (not rows) - Python

Tags: csv

I am trying to write two lists to a csv file. I want the lists to feed vertically into the spreadsheet into two columns.

```
import csv
import os

name = "rr"
newname = name+".csv"
rs = [1,2,3,4]
dr = [2,3,4,5]


with open(newname, 'w') as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerow(rs)
    writer.writerow(dr)
```

I am getting this:

> 1 2 3 4
>
> 2 3 4 5

I want this:

> 1   2
>
> 2   3
>
> 3   4
>
> 4   5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your example lists you could do:

```
rs = [1,2,3,4]
dr = [2,3,4,5]
output = ""
for r in zip(rs, dr):
    output += str(str(r[0]) + " " + str(r[1]) + "\n")
#now write the output etc.
```

This is not complete regarding the loop and lacks the writing. But I think what you actually wanted was, what the zip-builtin provides.
Explanation of what zip() does taken from [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

> This function returns a list of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables.